# UIImagePickerController detecting when photo goes into edit mode

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I've added a custom button to `UIImagePicker` like below:

[image]

It is just an `UIButton` set as the overlay view. However when the camera goes into the edit mode the button is in the way:

[image]

Is there anyway to detect the shutter button has been pressed? That way I could just hide the button. I know I can use 
`func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])`

however this is AFTER "Use Photo" has been tapped. I need to detect before the edit view comes in. Any pointers on this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With default `UIImagePickerView`, its not possible.

You don't get notified when the user taps the button but you can provide your own capture button

Hide its standard image picker controls (showsCameraControls) and provide a custom overlay view (cameraOverlayView). In that overlay view, place a custom button that you connect to a target/action.

Comment: I feared this. A lot of work implementing every single existing button again just to add another one.. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The `UIImagePickerController` is a proxy protocol for `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. Maybe try implementing the `willShow` or `didShow` functions from the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and find a check for this screen.

One way I can think about it to only show this button whenever the navigation stack have only one view controller, which will most probably be the camera in your case.